# How do I write a custom stream function

Tags: java

I know of the basic stream functions like:

```
mystream.filter(something).map(something)
```

Is there a way for me to write my own function that can be applied to a stream like:

```
mystream.something()
```

Chaining would have to be able to continue like etc.:

```
mystream.something().map()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'd have to implement your own Library which is wrapping the already existant `Stream` interface with your own:

```
interface CustomStream<T> extends Stream<T> {
    CustomStream<T> something();
}
```

That way you then have to aquire an instance of `Stream<T>` and then wrap it into an implementation of your own `interface`:

```
class CustomStreamImpl<T> implements CustomStream<T>{
    private final Stream<T> stream;

    public CustomStreamImpl(Stream<T> stream){
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public CustomStreamImpl<T> something(){
        // your action below
        Stream<T> newStream = stream
            .filter(o -> o != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream(); 
        return new CustomStreamImpl<T>(newStream);
    }

    // delegate all the other methods to private stream instance
}
```

With the above you then could create a `CustomStream` like the following:

```
CustomStream<String> stream = new CustomStreamImpl<>(Stream.of("Hello", "World"));
```

The only bad thing is that all the methods inherited from `Stream` will return an instance of `Stream<T>` and not one of `CustomStream<T>`.

```
CustomStream<String> stream = new CustomStreamImpl<>(Stream.of("Hello", "World"));
// returns not CustomStream
Stream<String> newStream = stream.filter(s -> s.equals("Hello"));
```

So once you use a method from the already given API you'll "lose" your customStream. To overcome this you'd have to override the methods in your interface:

```
interface CustomStream<T> extends Stream<T> {
    CustomStream<T> something();

    CustomStream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> tester);
    // all the other methods
}
```

and then create always a new Instance of `CustomStream<T>` when a method from the original `Stream<T>` API is called:

```
public CustomStreamImpl<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> tester){
    return new CustomStreamImpl<T>(stream.filter(tester));
}
```

Finally you're able to achieve you're chanining:

```
CustomStream<String> stream = new CustomStreamImpl<>(Stream.of("Hello", "World"));
stream
    .filter(s -> s.equals("Hello"))
    .something()
    .map(String::length)
    .something()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

I hope this gives insight on how to approach your problem

Answer (score -3):

No this is not possible.

This would require extending the [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) interface.

### Edit

As mentioned by Lino, you could define your own sub-interface (or implementing class) that adds those new methods.

```
interface MyStream<T> extends Stream<T> {
    public MyStream<T> something();
}
```

You would then probably want to wrap a Stream object into a MyStream object.